# how to read certificate from USB device and send it to browser like firefox

Tags: c++, firefox, dll, certificate, pkcs#11

I want to write a c++ dll that read certificate from my USB device and send that to browsers like Firefox.And I should mention that i have built my USB device with an ATMega32A which have 2K EEPROM and i stored a sample certificate on that.
I have read some about PKCS#11 standard but i cant figure out where to start. Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not "add to Firefox" but you can expose your data to firefox and make them available for use. To do this you need to *implement* PKCS#11 API and create so-called PKCS#11 driver (the user-mode DLL which implements those 70 or so functions defined in PKCS#11 API). Those functions would talk to the hardware device in order to perform certain operations. Then you plug this PKCS#11 DLL to Firefox and Firefox can use certificates on your device.

Comment: Thank you Eugene. Now I think your answer help me to find the answer. So you mean that i have to Pile all the function pointers into the CK_FUNCTION_LIST, as it say in [PKCS11.h](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-11/v2-20/pkcs11.h) ? and do the function i create on my token **must follow a specific pattern?**

Comment: You implement set of interfaces. I.e. you take all function declarations from PKCS#11 standard (all those about 70 functions) and create those exact functions which must behave exactly as described in specification. All your functions are exported from the DLL. You don't need to populate any list with pointers - you just declare those functions as exportable and check that in the DLL they are exported by name and unmangled.

Comment: and last question on this topic. what about storing pub/pri-key and certificate on my token EEPROM. is there any important security issue that i should worry about except making EEPROM read-only?

Comment: Well, that makes a totally different question which you need to ask as a new question on StackOverflow (or maybe on http://security.stackexchange.com ).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're creating a PKI hardware device. I think your biggest hurdle will be accessing the ATMega32. It'll be up to you to implement an interface on the ATMega side, be that a RS232-usb bridge, USB Mass Storage, or proprietary with a custom driver.

A simple solution might be to use a USB Mass Storage interface to present a certificate as file on a pseudo disk.

Taking the custom driver route, Firefox (and other Mozilla products) use libraries that have interfaces for PKI hardware. See [NSS](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/faq.html) and [OpenSC](http://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/PKCS11).
At a guess it's possible that there's a PKI / PKCS11 driver API for Windows that you can implement.

Comment: yes i want to create a sample token. i programmed the atmega32 and i can send parameter and get answer from that in program like Terminal(by Bray). NSS i think is to be used with C#, java and ... but i want to write dll with c++. and i used OpenSC but it don't detect my usb device as token. is there any solution that i can comunicate with OpenSC?

Comment: @osyan I see openSC supports a range of hardware. You've implemented an RS232 interface. How does this related to the supported hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: write a dll that can read data from the USB device.  You could use Winusb.  This will require the firmware to support it.

Step 2: write a dll that can add a certificate to Firefox

Step 3:  combine previous steps into one dll

If you get stuck on something specific, write a new question and show us what you have done so far.